# how to define an entity inside the function symfony 5

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony5

for exemple this is my function :

```
   /**
 *   @Route("/companyProfile/{id_Adresse}/{id_Employes}/{id_Contact}", name="company_profile")
 * @ParamConverter("Adresse", options={"mapping": {"id_Adresse" : "id"}})
 * @ParamConverter("Employes", options={"mapping": {"id_Employes"   : "id"}})
 * @ParamConverter("Contact", options={"mapping": {"id_Contact"   : "id"}})
 */
public function index(Adresse $adresse , Employes $employes , Contact $contact,ContactRepository $contactrepository, EmployesRepository $employesrepository , AdresseRepository $adresserepository ): Response
{   
    $contactform=$this->createForm(ContactType::class, $Contact);
    $employesform=$this->createForm(EmployesType::class, $Employes);
    $adresseform=$this->createForm(AdresseType::class, $Adresse);
    return $this->render('companyProfile.html.twig', [
        'Contact' => $contactrepository->findAll(),
        'Employes' => $employesrepository->findAll(),
        'Adresse' => $adresserepository->findAll(),
        'contactform'=>$contactform->createView(),
        'employesform'=>$employesform->createView(),
        'adresseform'=>$adresseform->createView()
    ]);
}
```

as you can see i declare all my entity in the parameter but i need to add all there ids in the route and that's not what i need , i just want my route to be like this :

```
   /*
   *@Route ("/companyProfile", name="company_profile")
   */
```

thanks in advance for all your answer

Comment: Where exactly does the id_Contact value come from if not the route?

Answer (score 0):

The param converter goal is the retrieve an entity from a route parameter. My guess is that you want to get all this entities but not with their ids in the route.

To do so, you will need to get the repository for each of your entity and then get them here. There is a question still : how do you know which entity do you want?

Here is an exemple of your action

```
/**
 * @Route("/companyProfile", name="company_profile")
 */
public function index(ContactRepository $contactRepository, EmployesRepository $employesRepository , AdresseRepository $adresseRepository): Response
{   
    $contactform = $this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contactRepository->find($contactId);
    $employesform = $this->createForm(EmployesType::class, $employesRepository->find($employesId);
    $adresseform = $this->createForm(AdresseType::class, $adresseRepository->find($adresseId);

    return $this->render('companyProfile.html.twig', [
        'Contact' => $contactrepository->findAll(),
        'Employes' => $employesrepository->findAll(),
        'Adresse' => $adresserepository->findAll(),
        'contactform'=>$contactform->createView(),
        'employesform'=>$employesform->createView(),
        'adresseform'=>$adresseform->createView()
    ]);
}
```

You still need a way to get all this new ids variables, but I can't help you more with the given informations.

Comment: i didn't understandyour question very well

Comment: Well in my exemple, I search for a contact, employes and adresse entity with an id for each of them, but I don't know how you want retrieve them from the db. Is this with a fix id, or maybe you have a different way to get this ids ?

Comment: yeah i just want to display all of them i don't need id to specify which one i need

Answer (score 0):

i tried a different way to display them but when i want to edit for exemple contact , it dosen't work  and they show me this error:
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined index: Contact").
here's a screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oZqW.png)

and here's my code :

```
    /**
 * @Route("/companyProfile/", name="company_profile")
 */
public function index(): Response
{   
    $Contact = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Contact::class)
            ->findAll();
    $Employes = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Employes::class)
            ->findAll();
    $Adresse = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Adresse::class)
            ->findAll();


    return $this->render('companyProfile.html.twig', [
        'Contact' => $Contact,
        'Employes' => $Employes,
        'Adresse' => $Adresse,

    ]);
}
```

this is the edit function:

```
    /** 
 * @Route("/UpdateContact/{id}",name="editcontact")
 */
public function EditContact(Contact $contact , Request $request ,ManagerRegistry $manager)
{
     $contactform=$this->createForm(ContactType::class, $contact);
                
     $contactform->handleRequest($request);
     if($contactform->isSubmitted() && $contactform->isValid())
     {
         
        $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $manager->persist($contact);
        $manager->flush();
        return $this->redirectToRoute('company_profile');    
         }

    return $this->render('companyProfile.html.twig', [
        'contactform'=>$contactform->createView()
     ]);
}
```

and last my twig :

```
  <div class="boxed-list margin-bottom-60">
            <div class="boxed-list-headline">
                <h3><i class="icon-material-outline-business-center"></i> les contactes d'entreprise</h3>
            </div>
            </br>
            {% for Contact in Contact %}
            <div class="listings-container compact-list-layout">
                  <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                    <h3>Contact</h3>
                    </br></br>
                <div class="container pt-3">
                    <h5>Responsable:</h5>
                    <p>{{Contact.responsable}}</p>
                    <h5>N° de tele:</h5>
                    <p>{{Contact.telephone}}</p>
                    <h5>Addresse email:</h5>
                    <p>{{Contact.email}}</p>
                    <h5>Note:</h5>
                    <p>{{Contact.note}}</p>
                    <div class="centered-button margin-top-35">
                    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
                    Modifier
                    </button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                    <div class="modal-dialog">
                        <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        
                            <!-- Form -->
                        <form method="post" id="add-note">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="nom">Responsable:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{Contact.responsable}}" id="nom">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="tele">N° de tele:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{Contact.telephone}}" id="telephone">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">Email address:</label>
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="{{Contact.email}}" id="email">
                        </div>
                            <label for="note">Note:</label>
                            <textarea name="textarea" cols="10" placeholder="{{Contact.note}}" class="with-border"></textarea>
                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                        <a href="{{ path ('editcontact',{"id":Contact.id})}}" class="popup-with-zoom-anim button button-sliding-icon"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button><i class="icon-material-outline-arrow-right-alt"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Please don't post additional information as an answer, but [edit] the original question to include it, although this case could warrant a new question, since it's different enough. That said, your twig seems to be incomplete, you are using the same template in different functions, but not passing the same variables, that's why "is not defined".

Comment: i'm sorry i didn't know ,it's my first time using this web site , and thank you for your answer

Comment: {% for Contact in Contact %}